# How is it grammatical to say "for the time being"? Shouldn't we say "for the being time"? "Being" is an adjective, and adjectives go before the noun

Tags: syntax

How is it grammatical to say "for the time being"? Shouldn't we say "for the being time"? "Being" is an adjective (a participle of the verb "to be", and participles are adjectives), and adjectives go before the noun they modify (in this case, "time").

Comment: Idioms don't always use usual modern grammar.

Comment: ***Remaining*** is more obviously an "adjective" in [*for the time **remaining*** / *for the **remaining** time*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+the+time+remaining%2Cfor+the+remaining+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) As that chart shows, the former case ("adjective before noun") is more common - but there are many written instances of the latter, so there's not much of a "rule" involved. In any case, as @Showsni says, idioms don't necessarily standard syntax.

Comment: See [Origins of the phrase "for the time being"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331556/origins-of-the-phrase-for-the-time-being) as asked on ELL some years ago. We can't vote to migrate questions from ELL to ELU, but arguably that's where the current question belongs, too.

Comment: **being** can be a clausal post-modifier. *You'd have to take that matter to the judge presiding*.

Comment: @FlatAssembler "Doug saw fish. He watched them *swimming*. He counted 5 fish *swimming* in the koi pond." Compare this to "Doug saw *tropical* fish. He spotted 3 *tropical* fish in the aquarium." Here, *swimming* can either pre- or postmodify the noun ("swimming fish" and "fish swimming" can both be correct), while *tropical* can only premodify, not postmodify (so, "tropical fish" but not "fish tropical"). This is a distinction that may be relevant to your question - ordinary adjectives **almost never** postmodify nouns, but non-finite verb forms *used as adjectives* **can and often do**.

Comment: Just like the infinitive also can: an example is "This is the thing **to do**" where *to do* is used as an adjective to modify "thing."

Comment: So +1 to your question since I think you've hit upon an interesting difference between "ordinary" adjectives and forms of verbs which *function* as such.

Answer (score 1):

[For the time being](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/for-the-time-being) is an idiom. Idioms don't always have a regular syntax.

> An idiom is a combination of words whose meaning is not predictable from the
> meanings of its parts. It’s a L E X I C A L concept, not a grammatical one..

-ASIEG second edition